# Is there a way to convert a vcf.gz file directly into a vcf.bgz file?

Tags: gzip, bioinformatics, gunzip, vcf-variant-call-format

I don't want to unzip the vcf.gz file first because it's a big file and my laptop doesn't have space for it. I tried doing:

`gunzip -c file.vcf.gz > bgzip -c > file.vcf.bgz`

But it didn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: You should provide more details than just "it didn't work": Was there an error message? Is there some output? That said, I agree with @Pierre's answer. Here, you use a `>` on the output of gunzip, which redirects to a file (check that you haven't created a file called `bgzip`, by mistake). Instead, what you want is to redirect this to the "standard input" of the program `bgzip`, and the pipe (`|`) is the correct tool for this.

Answer (score 12):

try

```
gunzip -c file.vcf.gz | bgzip  > file.vcf.bgz
```

Comment: upvoted for this answer...how can the same command be used for multiple files? If its rename, it can work. But how can I do `gzip` operation on multiple files and have their file extension changed to .bgz?

Comment: @TheGreat you need to use a loop, e.g. `for f in file*vcf.gz; do gunzip -c $f | bgzip > $(basename -s .gz $f).bgz; done`. This will take each file and rezip it with bgzip. Note that `basename` will remove any directory from the filename, so the final files will be in your current directory - you could prepend the destination like this: `... > some_path/$(basename ...).bgz` to put the files in specific directory.